# Determine all values of $\lambda$ with which vectors $2, x, x^\lambda,\ (\lambda\in R)$ are linearly dependent for every $x\in R$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Vectors are linearly dependent if $\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+...+\alpha_nv_n=0$ and at least one $\alpha_i\neq 0, \ i=\overline{1,n}$. So, using this fact I write $\alpha_12+\alpha_2x+\alpha_3 x^\lambda=0$. I asume that $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 0$ and $\alpha_3\neq0$. Since $x^\lambda$ will never be equal to zero, $\alpha_12+\alpha_2x+\alpha_3 x^\lambda$ with $\alpha_3\neq0$ will never be zero as well. Therefore, $\lambda$ with which vectors $2, x, x^\lambda,\ (\lambda\in R)$ will be linearly dependent does not exist. However, we know that $x\in R$ and therefore $x$ may be equal to zero and then we'd have that $\alpha_12+\alpha_2x+\alpha_3 x^\lambda$ is always equal to zero, regardless what value we give to  $\lambda$. What is the point I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda=0,1$ the set is no longer linearly independent $\forall x\in\Bbb R$

Since if $\lambda=1, x^\lambda=x$ and if $\lambda=0,x^\lambda=1$